# Why my object do not affected with nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor, objects

When I use shader on a material it will change but the object connected with this material don't change ??
[image: here the red color does not change to blue !!]

Comment: hello, yes it should change the object, but please provide more details because it is a bit vague

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Maybe you don't have any faces assigned to the material, but as @moonboots said, it's impossible to tell without more information and thus won't provide you with good answers. Could you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/148021/edit) your question and add more information or even [upload your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: you need to go in Edit mode, select the faces that you to give this material, select the material on the list, and click the Assign button